# ActiveRecord hook to create row in database upon creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What would be the correct rails way to create a row in the Database upon creation?

For example you have a User model where you create a new User

```
User.rb model
user_id
user_id =1
```

Now Im look for a way to create a new object / row in Database for other models for example

```
Account.rb model 
Should create a new row in account table with user_id = same as user_id above
```

Currently I use a

```
  = f.fields_for :profile do |f| 
  = f.text_field  :some_value_for_profile
```

Inside my User create view so that some values are written to the database upon User creation but this is not the "rails way" and would like to use ActiveRecord hooks to do this instead.

Comment: Do you have the usual associations between user & profile ? Are you using accepts_nested_attributes_for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are collecting the data for Account model from the view, you should create the account record with user record.

Assuming there is a has one relationship between both(user has_one account)

```
#in controller
@user = User.new params[:users]
@account = @user.build_account params[:account]
@user.save
```

Otherwise, if you are trying to create a default account record for all new users without collecting account data at the time of user registration, you can have a after_create callback

```
#in user.rb
after_create :add_account

def add_account
  self.create_account
end
```